# Determine number of different values for a property in a collection

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have a list of generic type `List<TypeA> list1` where `TypeA` contains an enumerated type.

I'd like to know the most efficient and simplest way to search through `list1` obtaining a count for the number of different values for the enumerated type.

There doesn't appear a built in method within collections.

Here's the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace space
{
enum TypeEnum { E1, E2}

public class Class1
{
    public TypeEnum Eobj { get; set; }
    public double doubObj { get; set; }

    public Class1()
    {
        doubObj = 0.0;
        Eobj = TypeEnum.E1;

    }

    public Class1(double doubObjIn, TypeEnum EobjIn)
    {
        doubObj =  doubObjIn;
        Eobj = EobjIn;

    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Class1> list1 = new List<Class1>();
    Class1 o1 = new Class1(1, TypeEnum.E1);
    Class1 o2 = new Class1(2, TypeEnum.E1);
    Class1 o3 = new Class1(3, TypeEnum.E2);

    list1.Add(o1);
    list1.Add(o2);
    list1.Add(o3);

    // trying this only counts distinct objects of Class1 not of Enum Types
    var count = list1.Distinct().Count();


}
}
```

Comment: Could you please post your code? Thanks

Comment: Sure...updated with baseline code...but whilst i know i could write a function to do this, not sure the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this easily using the [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method. 
With your code you just need one additional `Select` call to choose the enum values.

```
List<Class1> list1 = new List<Class1>();
Class1 o1 = new Class1(1, TypeEnum.E1);
Class1 o2 = new Class1(2, TypeEnum.E1);
Class1 o3 = new Class1(3, TypeEnum.E2);

list1.Add(o1);
list1.Add(o2);
list1.Add(o3);

var count = list1.Select(o => o.Eobj).Distinct().Count();
```

Alternatively, you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in `Class1` class, so the `Distinct` would work in your snippet, without the `Select`.

Comment: Thanks...see code above. I guess i wasnt so clear, but i'm looking for counting the enum which are nested in another class.

Comment: @gwizardry Thanks, always illustrate your problems with code - it minimizes the chance of misunderstanding :-) I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, getting back to C# and nice to see these one line solutions!